# Create a filter query for Microsoft Graph that works equivalent to "contains"

Tags: search, filter, odata, microsoft-graph-api

I need to create a `$filter` query for the *Microsoft Graph API* that searches for a specific word in a string (the display name of users).

For example I'd want to be able to find all users that have *"Esteban"* in their names:

> Luis Esteban
>   Alphonse Esteban
>   Esteban Luis
>   Alphonse Esteban Luis

The following query works, but only returns users that start with *"Esteban"* in their names, not users that contain *"Esteban"*:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Esteban')
```

I also tried using `contains` instead of `startswith`, but it gives an error response:

> { "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.", "innerError": { "request-id": "e5ed5c30-4e62-4497-8976-1d38167e759d", "date": "2018-09-13T23:17:17" } } }

And even though the [Microsoft Graph docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters) say they support *OData 4.0*, they also say this:

> "The contains string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources."

I also tried other commands given by the [OData documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) and the [construction rules](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) that are supposed to be supported by `filter` and other query parameters.

In particular I tried combinations of these commands:

> startswith
>   endswith
>   indexof
>   substring

but to no success. It seems the *MS Graph API* has no support for anything except `startswith` whatsoever.

I tried both v1.0 and the beta endpoints of the API.

**Is there any other way, some smart combination of *OData 4.0* commands and/or query parameters supported by the *MS Graph API*, that allows a search equivalent to `contains`?**

*PS: You can try out queries with the Graph Explorer [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users?$filter=startswith(givenName,%27J%27)&method=GET&version=v1.0).*

Comment: I fear this is not possible, but I also feel there should be a way somehow. The MS docs say: *"The contains string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources."* Searching online, it seems that people have been requesting this feature since at least 2014.

Comment: Thank you max i will try to research and see if i find something and update the post.

Comment: It looks like it's still not supported, but can you not get all users and then filter them yourself? The only alternative I can see, from previous posts, is to use the People API which does support the $search query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, Graph API doesn't support your requirement now. My suggestion is to get the user list first and then do in-memory filter. This way also applicable to other no-supported Graph API.

Meanwhile, make sure to vote up the [existing feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/31838047-allow-ms-graph-proxyaddress-filters-to-specify-end) in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.

Comment: "This UserVoice instance is no longer available" :(

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be the only alternative that will get you the list you want without filtering all users yourself

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search=Esteban&$top=100000
```

As per this [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20201201185055/https://nilesh.live/2017/10/26/using-optional-query-parameters-with-microsoft-graph-api-part-2/) the microsoft-graph api only supports **$filter** with 
equals (eq)

not equals (ne)

greater than (gt)

greater than or equals (ge)

less than (lt), less than or equals (le)

and (and)

or (or)

not (not)

startswith

any
and **$search** is only supported for "messages” and “person” entities.

Comment: thank you for your help but the main problem is that i need to work with the table users and this table dont support the query :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search=Esteban&$top=999
throws: "message": "This query is not supported.",

Comment: I understand that but does this not effectively work with the same dataset and give you the information required? When I plugged this in to the default Microsoft graph explorer apis it seemed to work.

Comment: I tried this with /groups and it also worked (as of Aug 2021), just fyi

Comment: @Ricardo Guerrero it should work with /users.  The syntax is actually search="<field>:<value>", e.g. 

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="givenName:Esteban"`


`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="displayName:Esteban's Group"`


`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="givenName:Esteban" OR "surname:Esteban"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $search query parameter, but you must include the parameter ConsistencyLevel=eventual for it to work. Also, $top can have a maximum value of 999.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="displayName:Esteban"
```

Comment: This works great!  Not sure why it was down voted.  Thanks for the pointer!

The search functionality works basically to replace $filter for contains, substringof, startswith, and indexof.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution and it worked for me:

```
https://synchealth.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=substringof('Adam', Title)
```

Maybe that will fit your requirement ;)