# How can I filter messages by conversationId

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to fetch a list of messages belonging to a conversation.

```
            var conversationMessages = await client.Me.Messages
                .Request()
                .Filter($"startsWith(conversationId, '{message.ConversationId}')")
                .Select(m => new { m.ConversationId })
                .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This gives the error message

> The Contains filter can only be used for string properties.

I don't understand this error message, since the conversationId is a string.

Going by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409117/15470126) to another question, I thought that replacing `startsWith` with `equals` or `eq` might work. And that would be preferable because it's equality that I want to check for. But then I get

> Invalid filter clause

suggesting that `equals` isn't supported yet.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it in [Graph Explore](https://aka.ms/ge) and it was working fine for me. I have given the HTTP call - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=conversationId eq 'AAQkAGI0Mjk2NTQ5LTE4MjctNDE1Yy04Nzc0LWIxNzA0MDBkNDkwZAAQADdMKw2knP9Pj1rq9BpHpsc='`

[image]

So try something like the below code.

```
var conversationMessages = await client.Me.Messages
                .Request()
                .Filter("conversationId eq 'messageConverstaionid'")
                .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I tried to edit your answer to remove the closing parenthesis from the filter expression but it seemed like nothing happened when I clicked save edit. So if you have 3 edit requests that's why :)

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, I have edited the answer :)-